# What do you do when a user keeps pinging you by writing/deleting comments over and over again?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, spam, help-vampire

A user is spamming another user & I for help in solving his problem.

The spamming happens as he writes a comment with the @<ourname> and then wait a little... delete that comment and write another one the same way.

I've been trying to be nice, but after a good 5 such attempts, I think I've reached my nice guy limits...

*(Note that I consider this spam even though it was not anything bad per se, outside of the insistance.)*

Comment: Just flag the post for a mod and explain what is going on. The mod will handle it accordingly.

Comment: Classical help Vampire https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/help-vampire

Comment: @xdtTransform, Ah! It has a name! :-) That's exactly that kind of stuff. He edited his questions with corrections too... Argh.

Comment: @xdtTransform the welcoming term is "problem-related blood requester"

Comment: @rene, okay, I've sent a flag about that one. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexisWilke, Yes, you are not alone. At least yours is polite and do not duplicate itself when feed after midnight. My best Vamp has for help during 3 weeks

Comment: The best way to avoid problems with help vampires is... not to engage with them at all. Just down vote their question and vote-to-close it, if those are justified, then *move on*.