# A user uses comments to draw my attention to the new questions he posts. What should I do?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

A user uses the following strategy: when they open a new question, they go to an answer of mine (which is possibly totally unrelated to the question) and uses a comment to ask me to take a look at their question. Comments are not intended to such a practice. What should I do? Should I flag this comment?

Comment: Comments are intended to ask for clarification or add more information to the post they are posted under. Those comments you mention fulfil neither criteria. Flag away.

Comment: Related: [What do you do when a user keeps pinging you by writing/deleting comments over and over again?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388896/11682469)

Comment: I would ask them nicely once to stop directing you to their questions.  After that I would flag every other instance to a moderator.

Comment: This is exactly why I'm thankful that peer-to-peer messaging is not easily attainable on this site!

Comment: My suggestion: ignore the comments. Mark them as "no longer needed", if you wish. I'd also suggest to avoid immediately trying to answer the new question, unless you really feel inclined to. Or you come upon it organically. All in all, you, me, and everybody else is volunteering our time here. Please don't feel pressured into spending more time and effort than what you're comfortable with.

Comment: I would flag it as harassment because if I recall correctly then that flag could get their account suspended.

Comment: (@)MokeyZeus, Could you help me please? (@)MonkeyZeus, you did such a good job helping me last time! (@)MonkeyZeus I know you're online, you just commented on Meta. (@)MonkeyZeus please respond! (@)MonkeyZeus This is due in 15 minutes, hurry up! (@)MonkeyZeus I just failed my class, I'll never forgive you!

Comment: @DavyM Hah, I have and would sincerely reply "Sounds like a **YOU** problem" to several of those.

Comment: I think it depends on whether it is in fact "totally unrelated" or not.  If I had a new question that was related to a question that was answered well, I think commenting that **question** (not the answer) with a `Related: stackoverflow.com/questions/123` can be a useful comment because now those related questions are linked in the "Related" sidebar.

Comment: This behavior is extremely annoying and *not* acceptable here. Yes, you should flag the comments. You should also flag one of the associated posts and explain the larger pattern of abuse so that a moderator has the context they need to reach out to the user and tell them to stop. This is more important than flagging individual comments. That will work to get them removed, but won't do anything to stop the annoyance to you. (Comment flags are handled in isolation. Moderators will miss the larger context of a pattern of abuse if you do not explicitly bring it to our attention.)

Comment: ... and as the answer in the dupe question states, I think its OK to comment the answer if you have a follow-up question (which is by definition related).  But don't be a [help vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire)

Comment: @SecurityHound Please don't flag "every other instance" separately. You should only raise one flag (better on the post, not the comment) and you can provide multiple examples of the other instances while typing the flag reason (assuming you meant a custom mod flag).

Comment: @41686d6564 - The moderator said something different, so I personally, will go with multiple flags. I see no reason not to flag each instance (within reason), it could be days or weeks between instances, of this unwanted behavior.

Comment: flag the commant and ignore it, the name you nknow already, but this happens, to all specialist

Answer (score 28):

Flag them as:

> **It's no longer needed.**
> This comment is outdated, conversational or not relevant to this post.

The comment will then be deleted by a moderator.

As for what you do after, it's up to you; you can go and answer their question or ignore it. I, personally, tend to do the latter as I choose what questions I answer, not others. That isn't to say that if I find their question via another method (such as in one of my custom filters) I'll ignore it, just that I'll ignore the comment from the user.

Comment: You need to do more than that. You need to bring the overall *pattern* of abuse to a moderator's attention, using a custom flag on a post.

Comment: Though true, the impression I got from the OP was that this is a one off, not persistent.

Comment: Oh, I interpreted as very much the opposite of a one-off. Fair enough, though. If it's truly a one-off, there's no need to do anything more than flagging the individual comment for removal.

Answer (score 21):

This is plain and simple harassment - Stack Overflow does not exist to be an on-demand helpdesk. Immediately flag such comments for moderation attention with an appropriate explanation.

If the user is smart and/or just wasn't aware of the rules (reminder: not an excuse, it's *their duty* to know those), they will desist after the mods have a word with them. If they are a classic help vampire (i.e. the opposite of smart), they will continue, at which point you modflag again, and this time the mods will hopefully be a little more... *persuasive*.

Comment: I can be very persuasive.